# installing grails on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: grails, ubuntu

Using ppa to install grails on Ubuntu 13.10 does not work:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:groovy-dev/grails
 sudo apt-get update
 Err http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main amd64 Packages
 404  Not Found

 W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/
 groovy-dev/grails/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Checking
http://ppa.launchpad.net/groovy-dev/grails/ubuntu/dists
the dists do not include saucy

Is there a better alternative?
thanks,
-John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact there is an alternative. You should use [gvmtool](http://gvmtool.net/). Its the preferred way to install grails and all its friends.

Comment: Thank you thewidgetsmith, I wish I used gvmtool first!